# evaluation of calc formulas in orgtbl?

Tags: org-table, calc

in calc mode, 'subst (2 * x, x, 5)' is evaluated to 10, but in an orgtbl table the formula is evaluated incompletely to '2 5'.
How to force evaluation into orgtbl-mode?
Here is my example:

```org
|-----+--------+-----+-------|
| x   | -2     |   0 |   3.7 |
|-----+--------+-----+-------|
| 2 x | 2*-2   | 2 0 | 2 3.7 |
| x^2 | (-2)^2 | 0^2 | 3.7^2 |
#+TBLFM: @<<$<<..@>$>=subst($<,@<$<,@1)::@2$1=deriv(@+1,@1$1)


|-----+----+---+-----|
| x   | -2 | 0 | 3.7 |
|-----+----+---+-----|
| 2 x |  2 | 2 |   2 |
| x^2 | -2 | 0 | 3.7 |
#+TBLFM: @<<$<<..@>$>=subst($<,@<$<,@1);N::@2$1=deriv(@+1,@1$1)
```

(The example can also be downloaded from  http://ix.io/EaH.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear that the second table with the mode switch `;N` for the formula gives wrong results since the non-number `x` is replaced by 0. From the [org mode manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Formula-syntax-for-Lisp.html):

> If you provide the `N' mode switch, all referenced elements
>   will be numbers (non-number fields will be zero) and interpolated as
>   Lisp numbers, without quotes.

So we look at the first table. You can enforce an additional evaluation of calc by `simplify`:

```org
|-----+----+---+-------|
| x   | -2 | 0 |   3.7 |
|-----+----+---+-------|
| 2 x | -4 | 0 |   7.4 |
| x^2 |  4 | 0 | 13.69 |
#+TBLFM: @<<$<<..@>$>=simplify(subst($<,@<$<,@1))::@2$1=deriv(@+1,@1$1)
```

You are probably aware of the possibility for [debugging org table formulas](https://orgmode.org/manual/Editing-and-debugging-formulas.html). That shows pretty good what happens.